# I need to RDP to a server through a reverse tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a windows PC that is on network A and a windows PC on network B.  Also in network B I have several Linux servers.  From the PC on network A, I can ssh to any server on network B.  I cannot, however, connect to the PC on network A from a computer on network B.

```
                                                      Windows PC Local
                                                       __  _          
                              can ssh                 [__]|=|         
              .-,(  ),-.    --------->    .-,(  ),-.  /::/|_|         
           .-(          )-.            .-(          )-. 
          (    Network A   )          (    Network B   )
           '-(          ).-'           '-(          ).-'
               '-.( ).-'    <---------     '-.( ).-'    
                            can't ssh               Linux Server #1
     Windows PC Remote                               __  _         
      __  _                                         [_Linux Server #2
     [__]|=|                                        /: __  _         
     /::/|_|                                          [__]|=|        
                                                      /::/|_|
```

I would like to be able to RDP to my network A PC from my network B PC.  Is this possible using some sort of reverse tunneling through one of the linux boxes?

Comment: Thanks to the person who created the awesome diagram for my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Solution 1:* From your PC on network A, create a [reverse ssh tunnel](http://www.smythies.com/~doug/network/reverse_ssh_tunnel/index.html) with something like [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) by connecting to a Linux host on Network B. The local port should be `3389`, the remote host `127.0.0.1` and the port is arbitrary (lets use `6000` as an example). Then from your PC on network B, use putty to connect to the same Linux host, and do a forward tunnel. Local port should be set to something OTHER than `3389` (as microsoft RDP client will not allow connections to localhost, but it *will* allow connections to localhost on an arbitrary port).  So lets reuse the same port number of `6000`, the remote ip should be `127.0.0.1` and remote port `6000`. You then point the RDP client at `127.0.0.1:6000`   .

In effect you connect to port `6000` on PC in network B. Putty forwards that to the Linux host, which has been set to forward it to `127.0.0.1` on port `6000`. The putty connection from the PC on network A listens on `6000` and forwards it to `127.0.0.1` on PC A to port `3389` which RDP then accepts the connection.

*Solution 2:* Setup an SSHD on the PC on network B, and then you only have to do a single reverse port forward. There is [Bitvise SSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) which runs on Windows and is free for non-business use. Bitvise also do a separate client that handles RDP tunneling in conjunction with a WinSSHD. The nice thing about this solution it that is saves usernames, settings (like full screen and so forth), and can be launched from a save file and will stop you from having to set up/remember to connect the port forwards before using RDP.